# Overriding a method with polymorphic arguments

Tags: java, polymorphism, observer-pattern, subject-observer

I have an interface (called `Subject`) that has the following method:

```
public void addObserver(Observer o);
```

I then have another interface that extends `Subject` called `TimerSubject`. This interface is a more specific version of `Subject`, used for timing. It has a few other miscellaneous methods.

There are also the two corresponding interfaces, `Observer`, and `TimerObserver`. `TimerObserver` extends `Observer`.

When a class implements `TimerSubject`, it has to override the `addObserver()` method from the `Subject` interface. That looks like this:

```
@Override
public void addObserver(**Observer e**) {
    observers.add(e);
}
```

The problem is, I need the method to accept a `TimerObserver` instead of `Observer`, whitch would look like this:

```
@Override
public void addObserver(**TimerObserver e**) {
    observers.add(e);
}
```

This does not work, since the arguments are not the same as the arguments from the method being overridden.

So is there a way to override a method with arguments that are polymorphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few solutions come to mind:

Your TimerSubject implementation could implement public void addObserver (Observer) by throwing a RuntimeException if it receives an argument that is not a TimerObserver.  You lose the protection of the compiler forcing types on you, but late binding is fairly typical to "true" polymorphism.

Alternatively, your TimerSubject interface could simply specify a new method, addTimerObserver, for the new behavior.  Presumably your TimerSubject extends a Subject which already has an implementation of addObserver(Observer); if that implementation would be entirely defunct, you can override and throw an error.  But if TimerSubject really has no use for an addObserver(Observer) method and that method is entirely defunct, then perhaps these two objects are not as polymorphic as you'd like. :)

Answer (score 2):

I had to do something like this once, what I ended up doing was templatizing it, ie

```
interface Subject<T extends Observer> {
 public void addObserver(T e);
}

class TimerSubject implements Subject<TimerObserver> {
 // ...
 @Override
 public void addObserver(TimerObserver e)
 {
  observers.add(e);
 }
}
```

This keeps the addObserver method polymorphic and enforces the argument type statically.

The idea here is that if you want each concrete implementor of the Subject interface to add different kinds of Observers. So you make the Subject interface ask for it. By having the generic class T extend Observer, you can still guarantee that people using the addObserver method are only used to add in Observers, which is a bonus. This way you can write a polymorphic getter as well, something like

```
public T getObserver(T e);
```

filling in the types for any derived classes. This way

```
Subject<?> foo = new TimerSubject();
// add observer somewhere
Observer bar = foo.getObserver();
```

will also statically type check. (Note: I'm working off memory here so that last bit may not be totally correct, but there's definitely some way to get it like that.)